# Web based audio/video chat api provider (no webrtc)

Tags: flash, audio, video, chat, opentok

I had developed a video chat script for a website with opentok flash.But opentok stopped this flash service 6 months ago and they force their clients to use their webrtc solutions.So my application has became useless because of this.

For the moment webrtc limits developers about some key points.

- I need to access to user's audio/video device list programmatically via user's browser to be able to enumerate them, to be able to design a custom device selection window.(This can only be done with google chrome if the infrastructure is webrtc.But I want to do this with all major browsers.)
- I need to be able to make multiple streams from the same user from different audio/video sources.

Flash based providers were working fine for the needs above, but I can no longer find one now.
Can anybody lead me to find a paid/free api provider for my needs ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to let you know that OpenTok will in fact be able to support device enumeration across Chrome, Firefox, and IE (with plugin) very soon. Within a couple weeks, the next version of Firefox (39) will be released, and opentok.js will also have a release, which will normalize the different APIs offered by the browsers as one API for you to use called `OT.getDevices()`.

Also, OpenTok already has the ability to make multiple streams from the same user using different audio/video sources. You can pass an `audioDevice` and `videoDevice` option into the `OT.initPublisher(apiKey, target, options)` method using one of the values you get back from the previous method.

Today all of this works in Chrome, so give it a try, and very shortly you will have it across IE and Firefox as well.